# Vuejs emit from grandchild to basic parent

Tags: vuejs2

If I have component in nested component 3-4 levels and:

(1) wishes to send data from basic parent component to the final child I must send from each parent to each child props - its nice, but

(2) if I want to receive data in basic parent component from the final child I have to emit to each of the children and get what I gave in the int's parent  until it come to the basic component - is not so cool.

That's how it works?

```
<component1 @change="change">
    <component2 :data="data" @change="change">
        <component3 :data="data" @change="change">
            <component4 :data="data">
            </compoent4>
        </compoent3>
    </compoent2>
</compoent1>
```

And in each child component I will have:

```
props: {data: {type: String}},
methods: {
    change: function () {
        this.$emit('change', this.data)
    }
}
```

And in base parent component I will have:

```
data() {
    data: 1
    }
},
methods: {
    change: function () {
        this.$emit('change', this.data)
    }
}
```

Or it is best to do with vuex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to overcome this issue in Vue is to use EventBus.

create a new file, and name it eventBus.js and put the following inside

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export default new Vue()
```

Then, on the files you want to communicate from, import the file and use as the following

send event:

```
import EventBus from '../eventBus' 
EventBus.$emit('MESSAGE_NAME', payload)
```

receive event:

```
  import EventBus from '../eventBus' 
  EventBus.$on('DATA_PUBLISHED', (payload) => {
      this.updateData(payload)
   })
```

Comment: I found also the store pattern example here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch

Comment: Thanks I see something about EventBus on stack overflow but not need it at that moment and not understand that I can use it here

Comment: Yeh! using Store is a great option.

Comment: what about Vue3 ?

Answer (score 2):

Vuex or an event bus may be overkill and it will break your top-down component architecture.

### If you really need one way data flow with a trigger and a result passed down:

You could do it react style: **pass the change function down as a prop** (it has access to parent data via closure), simply call it in the child.  You could even use provide/inject.

```
<component1 :change="change">
    <component2 :data="data" :change="change">
        <component3 :data="data" :change="change">
            <component4 :data="data" :change="change">
            </compoent4>
        </compoent3>
    </compoent2>
</compoent1>
```

**Component 1**

```
props: {data: {type: String}},
methods: {
    change: function () {
        this.$emit('change', this.data)
    }
}
```

**Component 4**

```
props: {data: {type: String}, change: Function},
methods: {
    // no methods required! just call: this.change();
}
```

### If you really just want a deep two way binding:

Instead of passing data down as a string prop, you could **pass an object containing data down** (you could even use provide/inject to skip layers).  Then you don't need a change function you can just manipulate the data directly.  As always, you can use provide/inject to skip layers.

```
<component1 :data="data">
    <component2 :obj="obj">
        <component3 :obj="obj" >
            <component4 :obj="obj">
            </compoent4>
        </compoent3>
    </compoent2>
</compoent1>
```

**Component 1**

```
props: {data: {type: String}},
computed: {
    obj: function () {
        return {data: this.data};
    }
}
```

**Component 4**

```
props: {obj: {type: Object}},
methods: {
    change: function (newValue) {
        this.obj.data = newValue;
    }
}
```